# Templating login view in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, templating, laravel-routing

So, I was wondering which is the best way include a single view (`views/login.blade.php`) into a layout loader, so I won't have to repeat all the code again.

This is my route that loads the login view:

```
Route::get('login', function() {
    return View::make('login');
});
```

And I've read the [Templating in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524712/templating-in-laravel) but they talk about controllers or blade layouts, no routes layout.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found some Laravel Forum posts explaining ways of doing templating

- http://forums.laravel.com/viewtopic.php?id=531 - Routes
- http://forums.laravel.com/viewtopic.php?id=839 - Controllers

And this blog article:

- http://jasonlewis.me/article/laravel-controller-and-route-layouts

Answer (score 2):

You could instead use the controller route so that you have something like

```
Route::get('login', array('uses' => 'login@index'))
```

And in your login controller you have

```
class Login_Controller extends Base_Controller {

        public $restful = true;    

        public function get_index()
        {
            return View::make('login');
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use it like that:

login page is extending content section of main layout.
I like login pages with full page (navigation, header etc.)