# Displaying Content with laravel template without blade

Tags: php, layout, laravel, laravel-4

I have this controller method

```
class Account_Controller extends Base_Controller
{
    public $layout = 'layouts.default';

    public function action_index($a,$b)
    {
        $data['a']  =   $a;
        $data['b']  =   $b;

        $this->layout->nest('content', 'test',$data);
    }
}
```

And this is my layout

```
<div id = "content">
    <?php echo Section::yield('content'); ?>
</div>
```

And this is my test.php

```
echo $a;
echo '<br>';
echo $b;
echo 'this is content';
```

When i access this

```
http://localhost/myproject/public/account/index/name/email
```

I get my layout loaded but test.php is not loaded. How can i load content in my template. I dont want to use blade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you nest a view within another it's content is defined as a simple variable. So, simply output it:

```php
<?php echo $content ?>
```

Section is used when you need to change something on your layout (or any parent view really) from within the child view. For instance:

```php
// on layout.php
<title><?php echo Section::yield('title') ?></title>
```

```php
// on test.php
<?php Section::start('title'); ?>
    My Incredible Test Page
<?php Section::stop(); ?>

<div class="test_page">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Great! it is too simple i never paid attention this could be too simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you need render for it, not sure, maybe partial loading:

```
<div class="content">
    <?php echo render('content.test'); ?>
</div>
```

Look this sample for nesting views: http://laravel.com/docs/views#nesting-views

```
  public function action_dostuff()
   {
      $view = View::make('controller.account');
      // try dump var to grab view var_dump($view);
      var_dump($view);
      $view->test = 'some value';
      return $view;
   }
```

Or use instead blade: [Templating in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524712/templating-in-laravel)