# How to include a sub-view in Blade templates?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, templating

I am trying to set up a site using laravel, but I'm really having trouble with basic things that the documentation just doesn't cover.

In this case, I see that it says I can include one view inside another by using `@include('view.name')`. What is view.name? Where is it saved? I tried creating a file `app/views/view.name.blade.php`, but it wasn't read. How does the file name map to the blade name?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**EDIT: Below was the preferred solution in 2014. Nowadays you should use `@include`, as mentioned in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21753954/how-to-include-a-sub-view-in-blade-templates/21755728#21755728).**

---

In Laravel views the dot is used as folder separator.
So for example I have this code

```
return View::make('auth.details', array('id' => $id));
```

which points to app/views/auth/details.blade.php

And to include a view inside a view you do like this:

file: layout.blade.php

```
<html>
  <html stuff>
  @yield('content')
</html>
```

file: hello.blade.php

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')
  <html stuff>
@stop
```

Answer (score 292):

You can use the blade template engine:

```
@include('view.name')
```

'view.name' would live in your main views folder:

```
// for laravel 4.X
app/views/view/name.blade.php  

// for laravel 5.X
resources/views/view/name.blade.php
```

Another example

```
@include('hello.world');
```

would display the following view

```
// for laravel 4.X
app/views/hello/world.blade.php

// for laravel 5.X
resources/views/hello/world.blade.php
```

Another example

```
@include('some.directory.structure.foo');
```

would display the following view

```
// for Laravel 4.X
app/views/some/directory/structure/foo.blade.php

// for Laravel 5.X
resources/views/some/directory/structure/foo.blade.php
```

So basically the dot notation defines the directory hierarchy that your view is in, followed by the view name, relative to `app/views` folder for laravel 4.x or your `resources/views` folder in laravel 5.x

**ADDITIONAL**

If you want to pass parameters: `@include('view.name', array('paramName' => 'value'))`

You can then use the value in your views like so `<p>{{$paramName}}</p>`

Comment: and to pass parameters: @include('partial', array("variable" => "value"))

Comment: How can I include from any other folder than `views`?

Comment: You'd probably have to override one of the service providers in laravel with your own implementation. Unless you have a really good reason to change the view folder, I wouldn't bother: too much hassle for not much gain.

Comment: @Sam This does not work, `variable` appears undefined in Laravel 5.3

Comment: @itsazzad you can set different folders, check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28848517/1536172)

Comment: upvoted. But one more thing . if you pass value from within a loop it looks like `@include('layouts.polygon',[ 'field'=> $value])`  and in new created blade for a template view to be used I removed `<?php` and then it worked.

Answer (score 15):

As of Laravel 5.6, if you have this kind of structure and you want to include another blade file inside a subfolder,

|--- views

|------- parentFolder (Folder)

|---------- name.blade.php (Blade File)

|---------- childFolder (Folder)

|-------------- mypage.blade.php (Blade File)

name.blade.php

```
  <html>
      @include('parentFolder.childFolder.mypage')
  </html>
```

Answer (score 3):

---

if file is not in sub folders

### @include('view_name')

if file is in sub folders

### @include('folder1.folder2.view_name')

Answer (score 1):

One more interesting situation with directory structure in laravel, following up on @gwed great answer:

```
@include('hello.world')
```

would display the following view:

```
// for laravel 5.X
resources/views/hello/world/index.blade.php
```