# How change view folder in Laravel5?

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

I am developing an web application using Laravel 5 and AngularJS. I am using pure angularJS app for the client side and I am putting the client app files (views) in my `public` folder.

In Laravel 4, I could change the path from the `bootstrap/start.php` file. But in Laravel 5, I can not see the `start.php` file. So where do I change the configuration in Laravel 5?

Comment: i could not find on there..

Answer (score 30, accepted):

See line 16 of `config/view.php` (the "View Storage Paths" section)

```php
'paths' => [
    realpath(base_path('resources/views'))
],
```

So you might change it to `realpath(base_path('public/assets/views'))` to be in your public path.

---

## Additional Examples

```php
'paths' => [

    // src/MyNamespace/resources
    realpath(base_path('src/MyNamespace/resources')),

    // app/resources
    realpath(app_path('resources'))

],
```

- You can provide multiple search locations
- You can use `app_path()`, `base_path()`, or neither.