# how to use @include() inside bootstrap collapse panel in laravel5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm new to laravel. And want to call the file inside the collapse panel. When I use @include() inside tab-pane its not working properly... That file is not displaying...

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="noorsitab">
    <li><a href="#equipment" data-toggle="tab"> {!! trans('noorsi.equipment.title') !!}</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-pane" id="equipment">
    @include('customer.form')
</div>
```

I tried many methods to bring it out.. But I couldn't...
Can anyone help??? 
Thanks in advance...

Comment: see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21753954/how-to-include-a-sub-view-in-blade-templates/21755728#21755728

Comment: FYI - you haven't accepted a single answer for any question you have posted. You may want to rectify this as people are less willing to provide answers to user who don't support the community

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have a view with the path `resources\views\customer\form.blade.php` then this should work.

Also, see my previous answer for a full view of how `@include` works [How to include a sub-view in Blade templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21753954/how-to-include-a-sub-view-in-blade-templates/21755728#21755728)

Answer (score 0):

Enable tabbable tabs via JavaScript (each tab needs to be activated individually):

```
$('#equipment a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})
```

You can activate individual tabs in several ways:

```
$('#equipment a[href="#profile"]').tab('show') // Select tab by name
$('#equipment a:first').tab('show') // Select first tab
$('#equipment a:last').tab('show') // Select last tab
$('#equipment li:eq(2) a').tab('show') // Select third tab (0-indexed)
```

> Write any  of these code inside `<script></script>` tag.

Source: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs