# Display a section according Condition in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-blade

I have two return varibles from controller to view in **Laravel**.

```
return view ('home', compact('books','count'));
```

Now I want to display one section('content') **@if the conditon is true**
in my **home.blade.php**. How I can do this. Now section('content') will display @if condition is false

```
@if (!empty($books))
 @section('content')
@endif
```

Comment: check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21753954/how-to-include-a-sub-view-in-blade-templates

Comment: Remove `!` from `if`?

Comment: @if (!empty($books)) is not working ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@else`, `@elseif`, `@unless`

Here is an example

```
@if (count($books))
 section('content')
@else
 @section('your other section')
@endif
```

Hope this helps

Comment: if condion is always satisfy, i check $books value when if condion is false. It returns [] . What is this result means. Am I check @if($books !== null) instead of @if (!empty($books))

Comment: @anu you show `no records found` if condition is false

Comment: Yea but always true condition is satisfied even if $books has nothing. And I checked $books value when if condion is false. But $books echoing  [] .

Comment: @anu   you can use `count()`

Comment: Fantastic. It works. Greatful to you Sir.It really killed my 4 days. From where you get this count function. It is not in laravel documentation