# How to call blade file to another blade file in laravel?

Tags: call, laravel-blade, include-path, laravel-8

I tried
@include('footer');
to include the blade file. but it doesn't work. How can I do this?

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21753954/how-to-include-a-sub-view-in-blade-templates . Just call it like direct view, not sub-view

Comment: @vvpanchev it doesn't work