# Undefined variable: title, in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I´m define my method controller index() and I pass param title for show in my html view:

```
class WebController extends BaseController{
    public $layout = 'layout.base';

    /*Index*/
    public function index(){
        $this->layout->title = 'Index Title';
        return View::make('pages.index');
    }
}
```

But when I load the page return this error:
[image]

And in my 'app\views\layout\base.blade.php' i have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <title>{{$title}}</title>
        @section('metas')
        @show

        @section('styles')
        @show
    </head>
```

This is my route.php:

```
Route::get('/index',['as' => 'pages.index', 'uses' => 'WebController@index']);
```

How to fix this?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Your index controller is making a view `pages/index.blade.php` yet you re showing error from `layout\base.blade.php`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524712/templating-in-laravel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add an array with data to the `view::make`:

```
return View::make('pages.index', array('title' => 'Title'));
```

Comment: Yes, it´s works, but don´t exist most elegant method?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this, you have to pass the variable when you return the View::make(..).
When you would like to pass more variables you can use the compact(); function.

```
/*Index*/
    public function index(){
        $title = 'Index Title';
        return View::make('pages.index', $title);
    }
```

Example with compact();

```
return View::make('pages.index', compact('title','description'));
```

Answer (score 2):

try to write call your view from

```
return View::make('pages.index');
```

to

```
return View::make('pages.index')->with('title', $this->layout->title);
```